# apache Ant basename issue with empty input strings

Tags: ant

I have the below ant code which gives basename (for ex: abc_01142018.txt) of the file from location input.dir. When the file is available, it works as expected.But when there are no files in input.dir it is picking up a value which I am not passing. I am expecting it to be empty value.

I read about basename and its not mentioned anywhere about how basename works when the input parameter is empty.

```
<path id="ref-id">
    <fileset dir="${input.dir}">
        <include name="abc*.txt"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<property name="input.files" refid="ref-id"/>
<basename property="input.file" file="${input.files}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use Ant's `path` type or `basename` task if all you want is a list of file names without parent directories. The `fileset` type already does this, so just reference its ID instead.

Example:

```
<target name="test">
    <touch file="exists1.txt" />
    <touch file="exists2.txt" />

    <fileset dir="." id="exists">
        <include name="exists*.txt" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="." id="doesnotexist">
        <include name="doesnotexist*.txt" />
    </fileset>

    <property name="exists" refid="exists" />
    <property name="doesnotexist" refid="doesnotexist" />

    <echo message="${exists}" />
    <echo message="${doesnotexist}" />
</target>
```